# Parallelizing the pseudocode to work on a GPU: overcoming misaligned memory accesses

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu, word2vec

Here is the pseudo-code (taken from word2vec C code) that I am trying to parallelize. First, I will list the data structures with their corresponding sizes, then the pseudocode:

```
1.  long long sen[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH]  
// In the C code, MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH = 1000. Increasing this should be  
//fine.

2.  float neu1[N] (hidden layer values)
//N is the length of each vector. For now, max N = 400

3.  float neu1e[N] (hidden layer error values)

4.  float syn0[V * N] (input to hidden layer weight matrix)
// For now, we can assume that V * N is small enough to be stored on the GPU
   // In the test data, V = 72k words

5.  float syn1neg[V * N] (back propagation weights used during negative  
sampling)

6. float exptable[1000]
```

The input to the program is a text file. The program then processes it one word at a time to build a vocabulary. For example, if my text file has a sentence

> “Parallel programming is very very interesting”

then the vocabulary looks like this (because the code sorts the vocabulary based on the frequency of the words):

```
            {“Very:2”, “Parallel:1”, “programming:1”, “is:1”,    “interesting:1”}
                   0      1               2              3                4
```

After constructing the vocabulary, the code starts to process the text again, 1000 words at a time. The first 1000 words are stored in `sen[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH]`, then a neural network is trained for all the words in `sen`, and the process continues till we reach the end of file. For the above sentence, `sen` will look like this `[1,2,3,0,0,4]`.

Assuming that the training is done only in a single iteration, the pseudo-code is below:

```
for sen in text
{ 
    for word in sen
    {

        for (c = 0; c < N; c++) 
            neu1[c] = 0;

        for (c = 0; c < N; c++) 
            neu1e[c] = 0;   

       /*The variable window is a user supplied parameter. 
        It is used to consider the context  around a word in a sentence. 
        For example, if I am looking at the first word in the sentence
        (target word is word1), and window = 5, then the words in the 
        window = {word2, word3, word4, word5}. 
        If I am looking at the third word in the sentence 
        (target word is word3), then window = {word1, word2, word4, word5}*/    

        for word in window
        {
            for (c = 0; c < N; c++) 
            neu1[c] += syn0[c + word * N];
        }

        for (c = 0; c < N; c++) 
            neu1[c] /= window;

        //negative: number of negative samples to provide (assume it to be 
             //between 5 to 25)
        for (d = 0; d < negative + 1; d++) 
        {

            target = sen[random_index]  
            l2 = target * N;
            f = 0;
            for (c = 0; c < N; c++) 
            f += neu1[c] * syn1neg[c + l2];

           gradient = exptable[function of f] //f is calculated in the loop above

           for (c = 0; c < N; c++) 
              neu1e[c] += gradient * syn1neg[c + l2];

           for (c = 0; c < N; c++) 
              syn1neg[c + l2] += gradient * neu1[c];

          } //Negative Sampling ends    

        for word in window
        {
             for (c = 0; c < N; c++) 
                syn0[c + word * N] += neu1e[c];
        }

   } // word in sen loop ends

 } // sen in text loop ends
```

I am thinking that the best way to parallelize this would be to process the words in a sentence in parallel. Considering all the loops, I think that I should use `N` threads per word, so that a single thread accesses the global memory (`syn0, syn1neg`) only once per loop. Also, since all the `neu1` and `neu1e` updates are independent, they can reside in the private memory of the threads and get updated independently.

My main concerns right now are the following:

1. Global memory accesses are happening in a random fashion, because `syn0` and `syn1neg` are accessed based on the value (index in the vocabulary) of the `word` variable. And, as we can see words in a sentence do not appear in any order.

Is this a big problem? Or, can we hide the memory latency by giving enough number of threads to the GPU? Also, I don't understand if this access pattern is actually random, because the N threads/word will access sequential data in syn0 and syn1neg, but the next set of N threads may access sequential data which is lying far away in the memory.

2. In the negative sampling loop, a reduction operation needs to be performed. The variable `f` is a summation of dot products. The problem is that I am planning to store `neu1` in the private memory of each thread, whereas `syn1neg` is in the global memory.

Would the negative sampling require a separate kernel? It looks like it requires a different approach than just launching N threads/word, but I am not sure what approach would work best.

Apart from these concerns, please suggest if there are issues with the way I am approaching this code.

Comment: This is a very broad question and I don't think it is reasonbly answerable as posted. "Tell me what problems you see in code I haven't written yet" is a really difficult question to answer with any form of precision.

Answer (score -2):

<sub>**Prologue:** you have opened a can of worms ( even without a `SLOC` present ) so **hope you can accept remarks presented per-partés** as the elephant-slicing seems to be the only approach to address the complex subject as a whole, not "escaping" from the principal issues downunder into a comfort-zone of an implementation-domain's individual lines of code, **where The Big Picture is typically missed**, if not already lost a-priori.</sub>

---

**`A1:` Yes**, this is a principal fact ( aka *"problem"* ).

**`GPU`**-devices were designed & optimised in silicon as a **`SIMD`**-**s**ingle-**i**nstruction-**m**ultiple-**d**ata hardware architectures, so they perform best with **both** code **+ data-layouts**, that does not need to exceed ( during it's whole life-span ) indeed small memory areas ( kilobytes ), that fit into `SIMD SM` core's on-chip memory areas ( **`GPU-SM-REGISTER`**-s without spillovers, ev. LRU-maintained L1-cache ) thus not introducing any "*idealised*"-performance devastating latency-penalties of **`about 350-700 ns`** per `gloMEM` access.

> `[B]-Fig.2` states:
> `TESLA` has **`SM`** with
> 8 [`SMX`]-cores **per `SM`**,
>  a pair of [`SFU`] **per `SM`**,
> a Multithreaded Fetch & Issue [`MTI`] `per`TPC ( a Texture / Processor Cluster )
>   **one 16KB `shaMEM` bank per `SM`**
>   one read-only `conL1cache` **per each `SM`** ( faster/lower coalescence collisions )
>   <sub>`[B]` TECH.GPU: NVIDIA CUDA C Programming Guide, [PG-02829-001_v7.0]; 2015/03</sub>

This works fine for raster-image processing ( processing 2D-arrays of data in a small-tile organised matrix-convolution calculus style ) where at the same ( well, sure, **`warpSize`**-segmented ) time **all threads perform the same `SIMD`-instruction** on ( ***ideally*** ) non-colliding data-cell(s) -- this fits the `GPGPU` best.

That also means, that any real-life operations, that do not allow such uniquelly step-wise progressive fully-aligned `SIMD`-ops will and naturally do block performance ( threads can but wait for inter-thread divergences, for (re)-syncing-barriers, for remote-memory accesses until data delivery finally takes place & thus latency-masking is less and less indeed **hiding** these natural obstacles from beholding an illusion of a true **`PARALLEL`** code-execution ).

---

**`A2:` No,** practically not much. In-situ benchmarking methodologies and proofs available to quantitatively evaluate influence thereof and demonstrate the limits of the range of resulting execution times.

While there is some help from a kernel-deployment directive **`__launch_bounds__()`**:

```
__global__ void
__launch_bounds__( 1,     // dim3tbGridSIZE <maxThreadsPerBLOCK>         COMPILE-TIME_ADVICE_FOR_OPTIMISING_COMPILER_____________REGISTERs, CACHE_, FETCH_, PROXIMITY_PATTERNs ANALYSES
                   1  /*, // dim3tBlockSIZE <minBlocksPerMULTIPROCESSOR> COMPILE-TIME_ADVICE_FOR_OPTIMISING_COMPILER_____________OPTIMUM_SCHEDULE_TO_FILL_FETCH_LATENCIES
                   ?,     // iAsyncSeqOfCmdsQUEUE_Stream_ID <<- TO LET BE FREELY ASSIGNABLE ... NON-BLOCKING EXEC'd KERNEL
                   0  */  // iSharedMemSIZE
                   )
                 Device_printf_GPU_CLK( int const iTag ){
                        ...
                        return;
}
```

there are lot of papers published on extensive ( brute-force scans etc ) "*optimising*", well rather mechanicall adjusting, the kernel compilation for various launch parametrisation ( threading-3D-"geometry" ), the impact on a general assumption for code-design shall not be over-estimated, as the results are always kernel-specific ( and, in practice, just explore which 3D-geometry will suffer least during limited-resources deployment on `SMX` silicon inside `GPU-off-chip-MEM`-access hierarchies ).

While one may modify the threading-3D-"geometry" of the code-execution, the latency-wise most critical resources ( `GPU-SM-REGISTER`s ) are limited and cannot be "ideally re-used" by other threads on context-swaps during scheduling. The more threads you plan, the less `GPU-SM-REGISTER`s can be exclusively dedicated to a thread (  <sub>an overall static limit for respective Compute Compatibility X.Y is not the issue</sub> ) and the more off-the-chip memory accesses are going to happen during a real code-execution ( one need not write a `SLOC` for having this fact given, just follow the published architecture documentation ).

---

**`A3:` No.** An idea of kernel-separation might introduce an illusion of a potential benefit from another thread-3D-geometry arrangement, but your code will have more problems with paying additional performance costs for loading / shared-co-processing / publishing it's data-structures. Kernel-separation makes sense in a fully **`RDMA`**-designed code-execution.